# What does this recursive mystery method do?

Tags: java

I'm new to recursive methods and I just don't really fully understand this code 100%, or maybe I do, but can I have some thoughts about this code?

```
public static void mystery(int n) {
    if(n==0){
        return;
    }

    if(n%3 == 0){
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    mystery(n-1);

}
```

So far I know that it checks if n is 0 and if it is then it returns. Then it checks if int n is divisible by 3 and if it is then it prints out int n. Then it calls mystery(n-1)?
I don't really understand the last line of code very well.

Comment: It just calls the same method with a parameter `(n-1)`. So, basically it will continue to check all the numbers divisible by 3 from n to 0 and only print the ones divisible. Just try to write it down and dry run it

Comment: **First** make sure you have appropriate brackets.

Comment: Best way to grasp such things would be to actually run this code with different parameters, learn how to use a debugger, and find it out yourself. You then will not only understand this piece of code, but learn something useful.

Answer (score 6):

That method does nothing, it doesn't even compile.

Assuming it did however it just prints all the numbers divisible by 3 less than the initial n.( the call mystery n - 1 is running the function again for the next smaller int )

with the code

```
public static void mystery(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { 
        return;
    }
    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    mystery(n-1);    
}
```

called on 5 the method would check 5, which is neither 0 nor is it divisible by three. so it will call the method on 5 - 1 or 4. It will continue doing this until it hits 0. Printing out all the numbers that are divisible by 3 along the way.

Answer (score 5):

It will print all numbers from n to zero that are divisible by 3.

It will have the same effect as

```
void mystery(int i)
{
    while(i>0)
    {
        if(i%3 == 0)
        {
            print(i);
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

often you can use this approach (iterative) or a recursive method to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 5):

It prints out all numbers which can be divided by 3, starting from your number, to 3.

If your input is 16 it's output will be 15 12 9 6 3.

And what is mystery about it?

Answer (score 3):

Your code gives compilation error...should be this I guess...

```
public static void mystery(int n) {
        if(n==0){
         return;
        }           //Missing in your case
        if(n%3 == 0){
        // System.out.println(n);
            System.out.println(n);
        }             //Missing in your case
        mystery(n-1);
    }
```

It will print all the numbers divisible by 3 between 0 and n.

Answer (score 2):

What this method does is print all numbers less than or equal to your input which are divisible by 3

Answer (score 1):

what this does is to check if the number starting from `n` until 1 is divisible by 3

here's the breakdown:

- call function with a certain `int` as parameter
- print out the number if it's divisible by 3
- call the same function where `n = n - 1` meaning `n` is "one less" than the passed number
- the function exits when the passed number is 0

Answer (score 0):

it will print the nos from `n` to 0 which are divisible by 3.
assume n = 12. the answer will be

```
12
9
6
3
```